# jQuery Custom Scroll Plugin

Tags: jquery

I want to develop a jQuery plugin that instead of having scrollbars, it instead has scroll "buttons" on the top and button of a container.  The container itself is just an unordered list as a menu on the left hand side of the page, but I also need to calculate when it needs to scroll.  The user can resize the browser, but the menu is fixed.  If they resize then I need to show the scroll options, otherwise I don't.

Another option was adapting [this example](http://valums.com/vertical-scrolling-menu/) so that it works for dynamic height dependent on the height of the current window.  Basically the menu on the left is always visible in the current position of the entire window.  No scrolling of the page should be required to see the menu.  It's silly I know, but it's a requirement.

**EDIT**

[Much like this](http://www.naterkane.com/blog/jquery-scrollable-plugin/#), but with mouseover as opposed to click, and it just needs to scroll instead of moving specfic amounts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery TOOLS Scrollable](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html)

Comment: It seems a bit overkill for what I need, and I'm not sure it will do what I want.